# Running streamutil.c and playfile from pjsip-app samples

Tags: pjsip

I am trying to run streamutil.c and playfile from samples but i am getting the errors on running them. 
On running streamutil, I got this error:

```
19:07:43.822 os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.1 for POSIX initialized
PJLIB INIT COMPLETE
19:07:43.825       pa_dev.c  PortAudio sound library initialized, status=0
19:07:43.825       pa_dev.c  PortAudio host api count=1
19:07:43.825       pa_dev.c  Sound device count=0
19:07:43.825          pjlib  select() I/O Queue created (0x7c87b8)
a.out: ../src/pjmedia/codec.c:53: pjmedia_codec_param_clone: Assertion `pool && src' failed.
```

And on running playfile, I got the following error:

```
19:08:35.703 os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.1 for POSIX initialized
19:08:35.705       pa_dev.c  PortAudio sound library initialized, status=0
19:08:35.705       pa_dev.c  PortAudio host api count=1
19:08:35.705       pa_dev.c  Sound device count=0
19:08:35.706          pjlib  select() I/O Queue created (0x13db7b8)
19:08:35.706   wav_player.c  File player '/home/udit/pjsip/alarma.wav' created: samp.rate=22050, ch=1, bufsize=4KB, filesize=265KB
19:08:35.706     playfile.c  Unable to open sound device: Unable to find default audio device (PJMEDIA_EAUD_NODEFDEV) [code=420006]
```

I have searched a lot and tried many solutions but none them worked. I thought there is some problem with my audio device but audio device is fine(checked with some commands like aplay-l, etc). 
Please someone tell me what should I do to make it run.

Answer (score 1):

The solution on Ubuntu is this:

1- Install **libasound2-dev**: `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev`

2- Recompile the Pjsip package

Solved my problem!!